# iPhone for which cases can't get mac address success?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mac-address

Use the following  method and work well for 99.5% cases, but very few users in **AppStore** report they can't get mac address (we use the **identifier** to authenticate every server call).

The failed case is based on iPhone 4S with IOS version 5.0.1.

Do you know for which case (besides low memory) it will fail?

```
/* Original source code courtesy John from iOSDeveloperTips.com */

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/if_dl.h>

- (NSString *)getMacAddress
{
    int                 mgmtInfoBase[6];
    char                *msgBuffer = NULL;
    NSString            *errorFlag = NULL;
    size_t              length;
    
    // Setup the management Information Base (mib)
    mgmtInfoBase[0] = CTL_NET;        // Request network subsystem
    mgmtInfoBase[1] = AF_ROUTE;       // Routing table info
    mgmtInfoBase[2] = 0;              
    mgmtInfoBase[3] = AF_LINK;        // Request link layer information
    mgmtInfoBase[4] = NET_RT_IFLIST;  // Request all configured interfaces
    
    // With all configured interfaces requested, get handle index
    if ((mgmtInfoBase[5] = if_nametoindex("en0")) == 0) 
        errorFlag = @"if_nametoindex failure";
    // Get the size of the data available (store in len)
    else if (sysctl(mgmtInfoBase, 6, NULL, &length, NULL, 0) < 0) 
        errorFlag = @"sysctl mgmtInfoBase failure";
    // Alloc memory based on above call
    else if ((msgBuffer = malloc(length)) == NULL)
        errorFlag = @"buffer allocation failure";
    // Get system information, store in buffer
    else if (sysctl(mgmtInfoBase, 6, msgBuffer, &length, NULL, 0) < 0)
    {
        free(msgBuffer);
        errorFlag = @"sysctl msgBuffer failure";
    }
    else
    {
        // Map msgbuffer to interface message structure
        struct if_msghdr *interfaceMsgStruct = (struct if_msghdr *) msgBuffer;
        
        // Map to link-level socket structure
        struct sockaddr_dl *socketStruct = (struct sockaddr_dl *) (interfaceMsgStruct + 1);
        
        // Copy link layer address data in socket structure to an array
        unsigned char macAddress[6];
        memcpy(&macAddress, socketStruct->sdl_data + socketStruct->sdl_nlen, 6);
        
        // Read from char array into a string object, into traditional Mac address format
        NSString *macAddressString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
                                      macAddress[0], macAddress[1], macAddress[2], macAddress[3], macAddress[4], macAddress[5]];
        NSLog(@"Mac Address: %@", macAddressString);
        
        // Release the buffer memory
        free(msgBuffer);
        
        return macAddressString;
    }
    
    // Error...
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", errorFlag);
    
    return errorFlag;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any experience on this issue?

Comment: Have you been able to recreate this error? I just tested your code on iPhone 4s 5.1.1 (all I had to hand) and it works just dandy. I could recommend the methods I use personally, but it's pretty similar to what you have...

Comment: en0 is only the wifi interface isn't it?
What happens if that interface is down on the device?

Comment: You’re assuming that the device actually _has_ an en0 interface (not all iOS devices have WiFi, for instance).

Comment: @clarkcox3: All iOS devices have Wi-Fi. It may be disabled by the user, at which point the en0 interface may be non-existent (not sure how that works), but all iOS devices have (had) Wi-Fi.

Comment: @scott No, you are incorrect. There are many iOS devices that have no WiFi hardware at all (e.g. the iPhone 3G originally sold in China had no WiFi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a situation like this after upgrading an iPhone to iOS 5 the problem was the infamous wifi bug. You are not going to like this answer, but the only solution was to take the device back to Apple and get a new one that worked properly. The code can be changed to not crash when the mac address lookup fails, but that does not help when REST calls require a unique identifier. As a developer, you are stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: Yes, you are right, no need to cost time on this kind of issue.